# How to migrate DOWN the MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, migrate-mongo

I am using [migrate-mongo](https://github.com/seppevs/migrate-mongo) library. I need to add some users to the application, so my colleagues can start working on it. 
My migrate up, is adding the users as expected, but the DOWN is not working. Well, actually, when I run the DOWN, nothing happens and I receive no error whatsoever.

My package.json:

```
"migrate": "cd database && node index.js"
```

Content of the migration file itself:

```
module.exports = {
  async up(db) {
    await db.collection('users').insertOne({
      'email':'ps@ps.com',
      'password':'$2a$10$VP6BKllje64JwyKU3.lBYumjjRQVvPsW/A5W9/XqleiDg4C1tZaB2',
      'name':'Hanah',
      'role': 'Content'
    });

    await db.collection('users').insertOne({
      'email':'wex@wex.com',
      'password':'$2a$10$VP6BKllje64JwyKU3.lBYumjjRQVvPsW/A5W9/XqleiDg4C1tZaB2',
      'name':'Vedran',
      'role': 'CustomerService'
    });
  },

  async down(db) {
    await db.collection('users').deleteOne({'email': 'ps@ps.com'});
    await db.collection('users').deleteOne({'email': 'wex@wex.com'});
  },
};
```

I have followed the authors procedure how to create generic files.

What is wrong?

Comment: try to drop the collection by using:
db.collections('users').drop() instead of deleting Ones.

Comment: That could work. I was hoping to be able to revert, not drop.

Comment: for explicit data entry and data removal, try to write seeds instead.

Comment: On the migration tool website, the examples are very explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but I have used the following syntax to remove fields successfully:

```
async down(db) {
    await db.collection('users').updateOne({'email': 'ps@ps.com'}, $unset: {'email': ''});
    await db.collection('users').updateOne({'email': 'wex@wex.com'}, $unset: {'email': ''});
}
```